# ErrorException: Attempt to read property on null in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I get **Attempt to read property "price" on null** error in my vodcomponent class when I am trying to use pay route while they are not related to each other.
i dont have problem with other routes of project.

**flareapp:** https://flareapp.io/share/V7jD2dLm

this is my **web.php** file:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\homeController;
use App\Http\Controllers\videoController;
use App\Http\Controllers\loginController;
use App\Http\Controllers\payController;

Route::get('/', [homeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');

Route::get('/login', [loginController::class, 'index'])->name('login');

Route::get('/{id}', [videoController::class, 'play'])->name('play');

Route::post('/verify', [loginController::class, 'verify'])->name('verify');

Route::post('/ver', [loginController::class, 'doverify'])->name('doverify');

Route::get('/pay', [payController::class, 'index'])->name('pay');
```

this is my **vodplay component`s class**, where i get error from:

```
<?php

namespace App\View\Components;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;
use Illuminate\View\Component;
use App\Models\Video;
use App\Models\orderModel;
use App\Models\User;
use Shetabit\Multipay\Invoice;
use Shetabit\Payment\Facade\Payment;

class vodplay extends Component
{
    /**
     * Create a new component instance.
     */
    public $iding;
    public function __construct($iding)
    {
        //
        $this->id = $iding;
    }

    /**
     * Get the view / contents that represent the component.
     */
    public function render(): View|Closure|string
    {
        
        $price = video::where('id',$this->id)->first();
        $price = $price->price;
        // dd($price);
        $videodata = video::where('id',$this->id)->first();
        
        if ($price == '0' || $price == NULL) {
            return view('components.vodplay')->with('videodata',$videodata);
        } else {
            // Do all things together in a single line.
            return Payment::purchase(
            (new Invoice)->amount($price), 
            function($driver, $transactionId) {
            // Store transactionId in database.
            // We need the transactionId to verify payment in the future.
            }
            )->pay()->render();
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my sample **payController** file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class payController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function index() {
        echo "hello";
    }
}
```

please help, thanks

i had tried clearing cache and making new route and controller but always i get error.

Comment: `$price = video::where('id',$this->id)->first();` change `video` to `Video`.

Comment: because of `use App\Models\Video;`. In another note, `use App\Models\orderModel;` change `orderModel` to `OrderModel` and make sure that both the model files `Video` and `OrderModel` starts with a capital letter !

Comment: Actually, make sure that all classes and their filename starts with capital letter too. `class vodplay` to `class Vodplay`, etc

Comment: @Mr.Kenneth
thanks, I tried but error is still showing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the route `/{id}` is declared first it matches the url `/pay` with `id=pay`. This would also cause the same error for `/pay`, `/verify` and `/ver`. So you should move `/{id}` after any other static route.

Comment: Or use [Regular Expression Constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints) to only allow integers for `{id}`

Answer (score 0):

I moved **pay route** to 2nd route in web.php and problem solved!
this is my new web.php file:

```
Route::get('/', [homeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');

Route::get('/pay', [payController::class, 'index'])->name('pay');

Route::get('/login', [loginController::class, 'index'])->name('login');

Route::get('/{id}', [videoController::class, 'play'])->name('play');

Route::post('/verify', [loginController::class, 'verify'])->name('verify');

Route::post('/ver', [loginController::class, 'doverify'])->name('doverify');
```

Comment: not sure why that works since route name has no conflict but good for you